# Internationalization with Messages not working in Production - Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, internationalization

I'm running a Play Framework (2.3) + Scala app and I've just started translating it.

I have the following configuration:

```
application.langs="en,es"
```

and also have the messages and messages.es files. I want the application to show the messages according to the browser's language, so I've changed it to ES.

When I run it in my pc everything looks fine, but once I deploy it it doesn't work. I've checked that both conf files for local and prod have the same values. I've also checked the request's Accept-Language parameter and it includes "es". The browser is still in ES.

I thought maybe I could change the languages' order in application.langs, but I want "en" to be my default language.

Can anyone help me?

**UPDATE:**

I've deployed a modification that prints the value of lang:

```
@()(implicit lang: Lang)
@import play.api.Play.current

[...]

lang = @lang.code,
date = @(new java.util.Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"))
```

and I get different results in localhost and prod:

- Localhost: lang = es-ES, date = 2018-02-20 16:37
- Production: lang = en-US, date = 2018-02-20 16:44

It seems in localhost the language is correctly overwritten for the browser language, but in production it doesn't. Does this make sense?

**UPDATE 2:**

So, I've been testing some theories... I think it might not be a Play Framework thing. Here is what I found:

1. Running the app in localhost, I changed the browser's language => the app's language doesn't change, it keeps showing ES
2. When replacing the "es" in application.langs for "fr" the app shows in EN, doesn't matter which is the browser's language
3. Renaming messages.es to messages.fr (the content is kept in ES) also has no effect, the app shows in EN.

Throughout these tests, the value of @lang.code is always the same: lang = es-ES. On the other hand, Lang.applicables changes from step 1 to 2: langList = Lang(en,)Lang(fr,).

What I gather from this is that it doesn't matter what language I set in the app, there's another place where the Lang is set and coincidently, it is set as es-ES in localhost and as en-US in Production. It has probably something to do with the Locale of the server. Can this be changed?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! I added an implicit parameter Lang to my template so it would get the value from the request header Accept-Languages. I then saw that @lang.code changed to "es"!

Just to be clear, you need to add this implicit Lang to ALL your templates, or it will just go back to a "default" Lang that I'm still not sure about where it comes from. So I have a main.scala.html that calls @header(), @footer(), etc. I added the implicit to all of them:

```
@()(content: Html)(implicit lang: Lang)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        [...]
        @analytics()
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            @header()
        </div>
        @content
        @footer()
    </body>
</html>
```